# Loading CSV File with Data Labels

Tags: qgis, csv, string, vector-layer, delimiter

I am trying to upload a CSV file with Lat and Long data in it and there are two columns that are not numeric (see picture below). Whenever I try and upload the file, QGIS recognizes it as a string file and loads all the data in one line, which isn't what I want. Is there any way to get this to load as a delimited text layer or should I be loading it in as a different layer? I tried loading it in as a vector layer but then it called the lat long columns "real" not "integer" and I couldn't see them displayed (probably because of this).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your CSV file as it appears in a text editor? It looks like whatever you're using to create/edit the CSV isn't formatting the newline correctly, based on the "BSD_Y_N ABA" field name in your second screenshot.

Comment: are you using a Mac? If so see [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/137260/55203) and the answers. Seems to be down to the difference in how line endings are handled on the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I have a .csv file (Comma-separated values), i.e. a raw ascii text file like this:

```
"House_number","count"
"1",103991
"10",81932
"100",4997
"100A",358
"100B",350
"100C",184
```

I load it in QGIS, using 'Add Delimited text layer', like this:

[image]

And it shows up perfect in the table afterwards.
Note that text fields left-justify, while number fields right-justify.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the new picture added above, you can see how it loads. Not at all like it's supposed to

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it wasn't working was likely two-fold. I had to save the file as a windows CSV not a normal CSV and also I had a number in the one of column headers that I think was throwing it off. However, it is now loading into QGIS properly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't hesitate the mark the answer that solved your problem... :-)