# Import 16,000 rows from delimited text file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, mac

I'm attempting to import 16,000+ rows from a CSV into QGIS in Mac OS via "Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer"

Latest version of 2.18 installed.

Once I've selected the file and hit OK, QGIS hangs and I get the "Application not responding" error when I hover over the QGIS app logo in Dock. I've had no problem before, but that was with < 2000 rows of data.

The file is 831 kb, so I figured it shouldn't be running out of heap space or RAM.

Data is structured:

```
postcode,val1,val2,val3,lat,lon,easting,northing
```

Is this too much data for QGIS to handle or a known issue?

I've culled some of the unwanted columns to test (e.g. val2,val3,easting,northing) and the problem persists.

For context: I am developer (mostly in python, Java) and I've recently come over to QGIS to make some spatial visualisations.

Comment: as you're on a Mac, might be the newline issue? see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137260/qgis-wont-read-table-columns-in-csv-import-on-mac-os). it may be trying to load in as a single line.

Comment: One thing you could do to narrow down the problem, is copy the CSV file and delete most of the rows of data, then try to import the smaller file. This will tell you if the problem is with the structure of the file, or the size.

Comment: @csk copy pasting into new file seems to have helped. Scaled up from 25 rows seems to work fine, 2.5K rows is fine, 5K rows is fine, 10K too and then all 16K is fine.

Comment: For whatever reason the exported CSV from excel kill QGIS, but copy pasting into new file helped. Probably UTF8 formatting problem that @StevenKay pointed to.