# Freeze adding a CSV file to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, osx

My Mac OX 9.5 freezes or does not respond every time I try to add a CSV file. I am using the following tutorial and following every step, but my computer hates it.

http://fredgibbs.net/tutorials/qgis/linking-and-styling-data-with-qgis.html

as soon as I hit the browse file and select the CSV file that I'd like to import

Comment: have you tried the answers to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/137260/55203)? This might be QGIS trying to load the whole file as one line, it's a mac-specific issue with some CSV files